# Securing a web service running on App Engine

Tags: web-services, security, google-app-engine, rest

Our application consists of a REST web service running on App Engine and a flash client. We need to make sure that only our client can make requests to the web service and to prevent situations like replay attacks.

I'm not a security expert (by far) so I'd like some advice with the security scheme I came up with.

The system will use a shared secret. The same key will be shared by the server and the client. I know that if the key gets exposed (e.g. by reverse engineering the flash client) the whole system goes down. Initially the client makes a login request to the server. The server responds with a challenge (a random number). The client sends back the HMAC-SHA1 digest of the challenge. If the digest matches the one the server it sends back the timestamp. The client will use this timestamp in the message (and message digest -- HMAC-SHA1) to mitigate replay attacks.

Baiscally this is it. Does it make sense? What would a tolerable time delta be for the timestamp when the server looks at a message (I was thinking somewhere around 30 seconds)? Any other comments?

EDIT: Oh, and what would make a good method of generating the secret keys?

Thanks.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

> We need to make sure that only our client can make requests to the web service

There is only one secure way to do that - ask your end users to enter a username/password, and channel everything through https.

As you already described, shared secret is pointless. It is trivial to extract that from the flash file. Why even bother going down that path when you know it is broken?

Comment: We can always obfuscate/encrypt the swf file. Besides I'm not sure what's the deal with https on app engine.

Comment: Obfuscation is just a minor inconvenience, it won't keep someone away too long. GAE supports https, but not on your custom domain. I have heard rumours they plan to support it on custom domains soon, but that's just grapevine. See this issue for more information - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=792